# One particular drive not appearing on Desktop and under Devices in finder, but accessible through /Volumes

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, finder

I've got a few hard drives connected on my Mac Pro. One of them is not showing up under Devices in Finder and in the Desktop, but does show up in /Volumes and I can go into it from there. All the other drives have icons on the Desktop and under Devices in Finder.

I've tried unmounting and remounting it, restarting, etc, it won't show up!

Running 10.10.2

Any ideas?